# Multinomial goodness of fit

Tags: sample-size, goodness-of-fit, multinomial-distribution, random-generation

Suppose I generate a multinomial distribution with probabilities $p_i$, i from 1 to k. Now suppose I test it back using goodness of fit (chi square) with the probabilities we know. I read that this works well when the sample size, N is large enough.
Questions
1. What are the factors that influence how large N should be so that the test works well? Hypotheses: k or the way the probabilities are spread out
2. What if we change one of probabilities by a small amount (say $10^{-3}$). How big N should be to be confident the test rejects the false distribution?

Notes:
1.the question also works if instead of generating, we have real data, the sample size would need to be bigger due to noise
2. this can be seen as a test that the generation was done without error
3. a program could be exemplary to test all these